# How to change docker daemon configuration on docker desktop

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, hyper-v, docker-desktop

I want to add tls configuration to my local dockerd daemon but since it is virtualized I cannot find where to change that configuration and Docker Desktop does not provider the options I need ( like tlsverify, tlscacert, tlscert or tlskey ).

i.e.

```bash
dockerd \
    --tlsverify \
    --tlscacert=ca.pem \
    --tlscert=server-cert.pem \
    --tlskey=server-key.pem \
    -H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/

Comment: Have you tried to put those configuration in `Docker Desktop->Settings->Docker Engine" ?

Comment: I did for many hours and it unfortunately does not work. That said later I figured out that I can debug it by signing into the docker's WSL to see the logs ( daemon was either not responding or was ignoring anything I would type into that textarea ). Unfortunately I've already installed virtualbox and used it for the SSL testing and development as a workaround and it worked fine.